# Pass multiple arrays from PHP through jQuery AJAX to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to pass the ID of the button pressed to my PHP script through jQuery's AJAX function. I then use the information to run a query that returns 2 rows, I save each as an array, respectively `$rTitle_array[]` and `$qTitle_array[]`, I `json_encode` each and I then want to send them back to my index.html and use them in my `generateProblems` function.

I sadly cannot figure out how to pass them back and then use them.

**Here's my JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    //Take id of the button pressed and save it as userID
    $("#buttons").find(".btn").click(function() {
        var userID = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'include/responseget.php',
            data: {
                userID: userID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success!");
            }
        });
    });

    var phase = 0;
    var rTitle = <?php echo json_encode($rTitle_array); ?>;
    var rText = <?php echo json_encode($rText_array); ?>;

    //Function to generate html based on query results
    function generateProblems(param) {
        var problemDef = param;
        $("#buttons").hide();
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            $('<div>' + rTitle[i] + '</div>').data('number', rTitle[i]).attr('id', 'problem' + rTitle[i]).appendTo('#testpile').draggable({
                containment: '.site-wrapper',
                stack: '#testpile div',
                cursor: 'move',
                revert: true
            });
            $('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>').data('number', rText[i]).attr('id', 'problem' + rText[i]).appendTo('#testpile');
        }


        $('#testdrop').droppable({
            drop: handleDropEvent,
            accept: '#testpile div'
        });

        //Function to restart generateProblems when draggable is dragged to specific place
        function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
            var problemNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');
            var problemCombination = problemDef + problemNumber;
            ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
            ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
            phase++;
            alert('ProblemCombination is "' + problemCombination + '", phase is "' + phase + '" ');
            $("#testpile").children().hide();

            generateProblems(problemCombination);

        }
    }
});
```

**And here's my PHP:**

```
<?php  include 'login.php';
if(isset($_POST['userID'])){
    $id = $_POST['userID'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT AnswerTitle, AnswerText FROM question_answers
    INNER JOIN question
    ON question_answers.QuestionID=question.QuestionID
    INNER JOIN answer
    ON question_answers.AnswerID=answer.AnswerID
    WHERE AnswerGroup = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      {
          $rTitle_array[] = $row['AnswerTitle'];
          $rText_array[] = $row['AnswerText'];
      }

    echo json_encode($rTitle_array);
    echo json_encode($rText_array);
}

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I simply do not know how to fetch or pass the arrays back to my JavaScript correctly, so I can use them for my function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data outputted by scripts is handled as single response from your script. What you can do is combine two arrays on server side to look like:

```
$response = array(
    'rTitle' => $rTitle_array,
    'rText'  => $rText_array
);
```

Then perform `json_encode` on this combined array and output it. So, instead of

```
echo json_encode($rTitle_array);
echo json_encode($rText_array);
```

you write

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Now as for client side, one of possible ways to handle response is:

1. Change your `$.ajax` request so that it will say the server that we wait a response in `json` format by setting `dataType` param to `'json'`.
2. Treat your `success` data as json!

Example:

```
var rTitle, rText;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'include/responseget.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        userID: userID
    },
    success: function(json) {
        rTitle = json.rTitle;
        rText  = json.rText;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I understand why I wasn't getting anywhere, cause the script is handled as a single response. Also, when you say 'output it', do you then mean: "echo json_encode($response);"?
Cause right now, doing "alert('rTitle = "' + rTitle + '", rText "' + rText + '" ');" after my AJAX, shows both arrays as undefined?
Again, thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: @user2304993 yes, I did mean that. I'll update my answer to clear it out.

Comment: Hmm, that is what I have done, yet something seems to be wrong. Removing my generateProblems function and putting in "alert('rTitle = "' + rTitle + '", rText "' + rText + '" ');" right after my AJAX, still within my click function returns two undefined? But clicking the button a second time returns the actual rows? How can that be?

Comment: @user2304993 are you calling `alert` before we assign JSON values to variables? You should first initialize them before using.

Comment: Here's the last part of the script, with the alert and end of the click function: "success: function(json) {
                        rTitle = json.rTitle;
                        rText = json.rText;
                    }
                });
                alert('rTitle = "' + rTitle + '", rText "' + rText + '" ');
            });"
I hope that makes sense? I think it is positioned correctly?

Comment: @user2304993 the first letter of `AJAX` technology stands for "asynchronous". Hence, if there is some code in function after `ajax` call, it will be executed immediately unless we specify `async: false` in request params. So, calling function first time and executing alert code will have variables be `undefined`.

Comment: I'm learning a lot from you, thank you very much. That made it work. Are there any downsides to using async: false like that?

Comment: @user2304993 it will stop execution of parent function so using `async: false` should only take place where it really needs to be. Like if you need to update some parameters of global objects and you depend on ajax call results, you should use `async: false` to work with latest results. However, such requests as `POST` used to just update information on server should be async.

Comment: Hmm, what would then be a different way of running my generateProblems function with the updated rTitle and rText when the button is clicked? Without having to use async: false?

Comment: @user2304993 call it within `success` of ajax call? I'm not really familiar with your task so this is all I can think of atm.

Comment: That does work, thank you very much for your time, again!